# How to get the selected drop down list value on button click without passing the parameters in angularjs

Tags: php, html, angularjs

I have a list of drop down.on click of button i am call one function.In this i need all the values which I selected how i can do this

The following is my code

HTML

```
<html ng-app="myapp">
<head>
<script src="angular/angular.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <select class="form-control" ng-model="firstType" ng-change="onRegionChange(firstType)" ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in items">
    </select>
    <input type="submit" ng-click='resultView()'/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

script

```
<script>
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', []);

myapp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope,$http) 
{
    $scope.Data = {};
    $scope.items = [{id:1, name:'First'}, {id:2, name:'Second'}, {id:3, name:'Third'}];

    $scope.onRegionChange = function(firstType)
    {
       console.log(firstType);
    }
    $scope.resultView = function() 
    {
        console.log(firstType);
    }
});

</script>
```

Any advice or help is much appreciated.

while clicking the button its showing error in console[image]

Thank you
 this is the error screen shot

Comment: show your `items` please

Comment: on change its working but on button click its showing 1

Comment: try `ng-click="resultView()"` instead of `ng-click='resultView()'`

Comment: both are same know and its not working i tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$scope.resultView = function(firstType) 
    {
        console.log(this.firstType);
    }
```

just you have to add 'this.firstType' then its working after a long day I found out this

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a parameter to `resultView` function. Like this:

```
<input type="submit" ng-click='resultView(firstType)'/>
```

And add here too.

```
$scope.resultView = function(firstType) 
    {
        console.log(firstType);
    }
```

Comment: I specified in question that i need a solution without passing as a parameter because i have thousands of values to pass